# XDebug Profile Not Profiling Certain Functions

Tags: php, rest, optimization, xdebug, profiler

I have a very slow rest api call that I'm trying to optimise. It takes about 20-30 seconds to return. I know that most of the work is happening in a function called requestBase->process(), but this doesn't show up at all when I use webgrind to view the output. The output in webgrind looks ok at first glance, there are plenty of other functions listed, but the Total Inclusive Cost column adds up to a several tens of milliseconds, nowhere near the 20,000 milliseconds that I know the call actually takes to complete.

I've turned on show 100% and turned off Hide PHP Functions in webgrind's user interface.

The requestBase->process() method uses call_user_func_array() to call the appropriate rest api, which in this case is a super slow recursive function, which again doesn't show up in the webgrind output.

When I turn on XDebug's debugger and step through the code I can see the slow function calls, but I want a report that I can categorically use to say 'this is x milliseconds faster now,' once I've altered the code rather than having to guess, 'well this feels a bit faster,' when stepping through with the debugger.

Has anyone had an issue like this before? Could the call_user_func_array() be throwing off xdebug's profiler? Any suggestions, either of a solution or of a way to debug what's going on would be really appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Toby

Comment: What version of XDebug are you using? http://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00000785

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are actually profiling the API call instead of some random other call / request?

Comment: @cillosis I'm using 2.2.3, so the bug you reference could be the problem. I'm not too sure on the best way to install 2.2.4 in ubuntu but will give it a try this evening. Thanks a lot already by the way.

Comment: @bspellmeyer I use the postman rest client to profile and to debug the call. When I use the same query with the debugger enabled, I can step through all the slow functions that I'm expecting to see including the ones that don't show up in webgrind. It's a good thing to check though and it did cross my mind, so thanks for the suggestion.